# Jars with same name of class file and with same package structure

Tags: java, classpath, classloader

I have two jars A.jar and B.jar and both have a class say test with package com.source,

I know i can get hold of test from A.jar if A.jar comes first in the class path.

I am looking for the way, to get access of test from B.jar if I don't have any control in modifying class path. So basically, what all can be done to access test from B.jar without removing A.jar?

Answer (score 1):

You can use URLClassLoader and give the exact path to your jar file.

```
    URL myURL = new URL("jar:file:" +jarfilepath+"!/");
    URL[] urls =  new URL[]{myURL};
    URLClassLoader cl = URLClassLoader.newInstance(urls);
    Class c = cl.loadClass(classname);
```